# Which of these approaches is the most "best Rails practice"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very concrete dilemma right now.

Given the following models:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :sent_at

  belongs_to :subject
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title

  has_many :messages
  belongs_to :last_message, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'last_message_id'
end
```

In a view I want to iterate over a list of subjects and display:
- Subject title
- sent_at for the subject's last message
like this:

```
<% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
  <%= subject.title %>
  <%= subject.last_message.sent_at %>
<% end %>
```

The thing is: **subject.last_message may some times be nil.** In which case, the above code will throw an exception.

So: What is the best solution to this? I can see 3 possibilities, but honestly don't know which are considered good or bad.

1) Let the view rescue it

```
<%= subject.last_message.sent_at rescue '' %>
```

2) Make a helper

```
def last_message_sent_at(subject)
  return '' if subject.last_message.blank?
  subject.last_message.sent_at
end

<%= last_message_sent_at(subject) %>
```

3) Make a sort of "proxy" on the Subject model

```
class Subject < ...
  ...
  def last_message_sent_at
    return '' if last_message.blank?
    last_message.sent_at
  end
end

<%= subject.last_message_sent_at %>
```

Which would you choose, and why? Or is there perhaps another way, which I haven't thought about?

/ Carsten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `try` :

```
<%= subject.last_message.try(:sent_at) %>
```

So, if `subject.last_message` is nil, you will get no output; else if it is not nil, it will call the method `sent_at` on `subject.last_message`.

It is like a convenient form for your #2 idea

[Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try)

As additional thought, helper is a bad choice. You ideally always want a "receiver" (in `some_class.perform()`, `some_class` is the "receiver" i.e. it "receives" the message "perform"). I avoid Helpers unless I need to generate HTML. So, your #3 does have a receiver, but since Rails provides `try`, you do not need to roll your own.

Comment: That is a very elegant solution - I didn't know this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing, in this case, may be to simply check for the null value...

```
<% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
  <%= subject.title %>
  <%= subject.last_message.sent_at if subject.last_message %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
  <%= subject.title %>
  <%= subject.last_message && subject.last_message.sent_at %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You do not have to explicitly check for nil if you use Object#try().

Comment: I believe try is considered to be somewhat of an anti-pattern... https://gist.github.com/1602530

Answer (score 0):

If you had any logic or action to perform, best practice would be to move it out of your views (into helpers, presenters).

Since your question is about "how to call a method on possibly nil instance?", then `try` is probably the best way to go in this case. Because, it's already there and you don't need any extra `gem`s.

On the other note, you can improve your code by just putting `render @subjects` and moving your block content into the `_subject` parcial. Rails will do the looping for you.

Comment: Quite true about "render @subjects" I was just making the example this way to make the question easier to understand.